# Can Phonon be used for capture or transcoding?

Tags: qt, kde-plasma, phonon

Qt/KDE's Phonon media framework abstraction implemented playback first. Can it do anything more complicated yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phonon, in its current state, only supports playback. The Qt team would like to add capturing in the future though:

> Phonon and its Qt backends, though fully functional for multimedia playback, are still under development. Functionality to come is the possibility to capture media and more processors for both music and video files.

[Source](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/phonon-overview.html)

Answer (score 3):

There is no API's in Phonon for capture or transcoding yet. Effects and capture is on KDE's Phonon roadmap which can be viewed here;

http://phonon.kde.org/cms/1007

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, [Phonon](http://phonon.kde.org/) is just a wrapper for the underlying media backend. Under Linux Phonon uses [GStreamer](http://www.gstreamer.net/) by default but it [seems](http://liquidat.wordpress.com/2008/04/10/more-phonon-backends-vlc-mplayer/) they can be changed. So if the backend can capture or transcode, basically Phonon could do so, too. Maybe you would have to extend Phonon.

Answer (score 1):

There is meant to be a new functionality in 4.6 called the QtMultimedia:

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6-snapshot/qtmultimedia.html

Its not complete yet but you can see some progress.